# Please tell me how can I pass the two dimensional array here to the called function 'getCount', also suggest any better ways to approach

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, function-call

**vector A[] initially contains all the elements, I've copied all elements to the array arr**

> The task is to get the count of Islands in given elements

```
int getCount(int *arr, int r, int c, int row, int column)
{
    if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r > row || c > column)
        return 0;
    if (arr[r][c] == 0)
        return 0;
    arr[r][c] = 0;
    int val = 1;
    for (int i = r - 1; r < r + 1; r++)
        for (int j = -1; j < c + 1; c++)
        {
            if (i != r || j != c)
                getCount(arr, r, c, row, column);
        }
    return val;
}

int findIslands(vector<int> A[], int N, int M)
{
    int arr[N][M];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
    {
        int temp=(i*M)+j;
        arr[i][j]=A[temp];
    }
    for(int row=0;row<N;row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < M; column++)
    {
        if (arr[row][column] == 1)
            count += getCount((int *)arr, row, column, N, M);
    }
    return count;
}
```